# Javascript/Typescript - Different syntax to import class

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

What is different between two syntax to import in angular:

```
import partition from 'lodash/fp/partition';
import { partition } from 'lodash/fp/partition';
```

First one is working but other is not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: For your clarification this is not a `Angular` feature. This is a `javascript ES6` feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is used to import something that is marked as `default`:

```
// lodash/fp/partiotion

export const a = 5;
export const b = 'b';
export default {key: 'value'}; // only this line will be imported using the first syntax
```

The second one allows you to specify what to import:

```
// lodash/fp/partiotion

export const a = 5;
export const b = 7;
export const partition = () => {}; // you are directly importing only this line
```

Comment: for more detail on how to use import check MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Answer (score 2):

The first one imports the default export from module 'lodash/fp/partition' whereas the second one attempts to destructure the module's exports and get just the `partition` export.

For this module:

```js
module.exports = {
  default: 1,
  partition: 2,
}
```

import partition from 'lodash/fp/partition'; would be:

```js
partion === 1
```

import { partition } from 'lodash/fp/partition'; would be:

```js
partion === 2
```

For this module:

```js
module.exports = 1
```

import partition from 'lodash/fp/partition'; would be:

```js
partion === 1
```

import { partition } from 'lodash/fp/partition'; would be:

```js
partion === undefined
```